Sping Kafka @KafkaHandler ignores message
I am developing a project with Spring Boot + Kafka. I'm having hard times with understanding why my @KafkaHandler not catching the event I'm sedning through windows commandline. To send message I'm using following command:
start .\kafka-console-producer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092,localhost:9094 --topic user --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=."
user-created.{"username": "test@gmail.com", "password": "test", "firstName": "firstName", "lastName": "lastName", "positionId": 1}

Json format:
{
  "username": "test@gmail.com",
  "password": "test",
  "firstName": "firstName",
  "lastName": "lastName",
  "positionId": 1
}

So when the message was sent it is immediately getting into DLT. I think it's connected to desearilization exception which isn't being logged (I don't know why, but I can't see any exceptions during the process). Here is my listener
@KafkaListener(id = "1", topics = "user", groupId = "users")
@Component
@Slf4j
public class UserCreatedKafkaEventListener {

    @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
    public void defaultHandler(Object o) {
        log.info("Received unknown event: {}", o);
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    public void userCreatedEventHandler(UserCreatedEvent event,
                                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY) String key) {
        log.info("Handling event with key: {}", key);

    }
  }

When the message is sent no logs from the class above can be seen in the console.
Here is my UserCreatedEvent class
@Data
public class UserCreatedEvent {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Long positionId;
}

Structure is the same as the json I am sedning in the message. At first, I was thinking that maybe I am sendig wrong object, so I added @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true) to catch all unknown message types, but still there are no logs in the concole.
Here is my consumer config
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;
    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String groupId;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
                groupId);
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put(
                ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS,
                JsonDeserializer.class
        );

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate) {
        DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler =
                new DefaultErrorHandler(
                        new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate), new FixedBackOff(3000, 3));
        errorHandler.addRetryableExceptions(ServiceUnavailable.class);
        errorHandler.addNotRetryableExceptions(
                ServerSideException.class,
                ClientSideException.class,
                DeserializationException.class,
                JsonProcessingException.class,
                MismatchedInputException.class);

        return errorHandler;
    }
}

And my producer config, if needed
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String serverAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                serverAddress);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                JsonSerializer.class);

        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG,
                "all");
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG,
                true);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG,
                5);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

I have no idea what can be wrong here, I triead to add and remove "id" attribute in @KafkaListener - but no use, I tried to remove @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY) String key and still get the same result. As I said, no logs from @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true) are being printed so I am not even sure if this problem related to deserialization, because if it was, then, I think, message would get to deafult handler and I would see at least one log

Any chances that you can share a simple project with us to reproduce on our side? Thanks

I think error is because you are using String deserializer while consuming json, you have to create custom serializer/deserializer if you want to consume json.
